# problem with navbar alignment of the first

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I get this script:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar bg-light navbar-expand-sm justify-content-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/test2">
        <img src="css/favimg/logo.png" height="40" alt="test">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that I get the next problem the first `link2` is not aligned with the main logo

[explenation photo of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76lZ7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problem in snippet but if you facing this problem, you can add `align-items-center` class to fix this issue.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar bg-light navbar-expand-sm justify-content-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/test2">
        <img src="css/favimg/logo.png" height="40" alt="test">
    </a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-center">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks. I guess the main problem was really crazy i changed it instead of 
<img src="css/favimg/logo.png" height="40" alt="test">
to this:
<img src="css/favimg/logo.png" style="width:40px;" alt="test">
some how it's soved the problem.
thank you very much nisharg!

Comment: Its my pleasure.